# Get all members of a group Atlassian Confluence

Tags: soap, confluence

I'm using Atlassian Confluence SOAP API. Is there any way of getting all the members of a given group?

I can use `getUserGroups` iteratively for every user. But obviously that is not efficient for a remote client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. NO you can't. The SOAP API does not provide that functionality.

Comment: but you can vote for https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-8437 and https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-5358 :)